# Dropdown using Ajax

Tags: ajax

I wrote the below code; when I select `India/America` in the dropdown related text files with some contents, has to be read and displayed inside a `div` element, but am getting an error in the line `xhr.send()`

**can anyone explain why??**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getcity()
{
    var a=document.getElementById("country");
    var b=a[a.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(b);
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(b=="India")
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if((xhr.readystate==4)&&(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==304))
            {
                document.getElementByID("display").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET","india.txt",true);
    }
    else
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if((xhr.readystate==4)&&(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==304))
            {
                document.getElementByID("display").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET","america.txt",true);
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="country" onchange="getcity()">
<option>India</option>
<option>America</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove `null` from xhr.send(null);

Comment: i tried Rajesh...Still it is not showing the contents in the text file...the contents are just a plain String

Comment: Remove xhr.status==304

Comment: what is the error after trying with `xhr.send()`

Comment: See this "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866761/xmlhttprequest-error" May be this will help...

Comment: i tried debugging the code in firefox..but the readystate seems to be 1 and not 4...can this be the cause of error...or is it because of the text file????

Comment: i tried removing it rajesh

Comment: Hey did you alert(xhr.responseText); in success

Comment: Rajesh did u try adding alert(xhr.responeText)...

Comment: if((xhr.readystate==4)&&(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==304))
            {
                alert(xhr.responeText);document.getElementByID("display").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }

Comment: Am getting an alert,,but it does not contain the contents of the text file that has to be read..

Comment: Check if your Code file and Text file are in the same folder

Comment: yes they are in the same folder

Comment: Hey I tried your code on localhost.. And it's working... are u missing to import jquey ` <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
`

Comment: Can u send the complete script tag for importing that script

Comment: Rajesh can u send the code with script tag added

Comment: Can you please provide your email id

Comment: or u can post the code as an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function getcity()
{
    var a=document.getElementById("country");
    var b=a[a.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(b);
    var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if(b=="India")
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if((xhr.readystate==4)&&(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==304))
            {
                document.getElementByID("display").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET","india.txt",true);
    }
    else
    {
        xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if((xhr.readystate==4)&&(xhr.status==200||xhr.status==304))
            {
                document.getElementByID("display").innerHTML=xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
        xhr.open("GET","america.txt",true);
    }
    xhr.send(null);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="country" onchange="getcity()">
<option>India</option>
<option>America</option>
</select>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But how come am not getting the output...do i have to do any port configurations????

Comment: i have the file locally stored in my sys tem,,,How would the URL of the file be????

Comment: Place that file in the drive path C:\xampp\htdocs\YourFile.html. And open browser and type in address bar localhost\YourFile.html. This is using XAMPP