# How do I log 500 server errors with XMLHttpRequest in pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I generally have been using XMLHttpRequest to perform Ajax calls. However, when the server has an error, I'd like to console.log the error so that I don't have to run to the server to see the event log there.

Here's what I generally do:

```js
function LoadPage(){
    var parameters="this=that";
    var x = new GetXmlHttpObject();
    x.open("POST", "Ajax.aspx?Function=LoadPage")
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    x.ontimeout = function () { location.reload(true); }
    x.send(parameters);
    x.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (x.readyState === 4 && x.status === 200){
            //Do Stuff with the response
        }
    }
```

But if the server has an error with the request, I get the error on the x.send(parameters) line. I've tried to wrap that in a try..catch, but the error comes up in the console even with the command held inside the try.

How can I console.log the 500 errors from the server using this structure?

Comment: *"But if the server has an error with the request, I get the error on the x.send(parameters) line"* What makes you think that? If it's a 500 error, you'll get it in your readystate callback. It's asynchronous, just like the 200 response you already check for.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866761/xmlhttprequest-ajax-error) might be useful.

Comment: OK - I get it. My Chrome console was indicating it as an error on that line, which is true, but I can capture the error with another x.resadyState == 4 && x.status==500.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But if the server has an error with the request, I get the error on the x.send(parameters) line.

That won't happen. The client can't react to the response in any way before the response has arrived.

---

> I've tried to wrap that in a try..catch

That won't work for two reasons.

- It is asynchronous
- It doesn't throw an exception

---

> ```
> if (x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
> ```

You're already testing for a `200` status here. Test for a `500` status in the same way.

Answer (score -1):

**Updated function**

```
function LoadPage() {
      return new Promise(function(succeed, fail) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        req.open("POST", "Ajax.aspx?Function=LoadPage", true);
        req.ontimeout = function () { location.reload(true); }
        req.addEventListener("load", function() {
          if (req.status < 400)
            succeed(req.responseText);
          else if (req.status == 500)
            fail("Error 500: Internal Server Error");
          else
            fail(new Error("Request failed: " + req.statusText));
        });
        req.addEventListener("error", function() {
          fail(new Error("Network error"));
        });
        req.send("this=that");
      });
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
LoadPage().then(function(text) {
  console.log("data.txt: " + text);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("Failed to fetch data.txt: " + error);
});
```