# if not authorized after Google OAuth, redirect to specific page

Tags: php, google-oauth

I got Google SignIn to work properly, but do not know how to only allow users already in my database. I'm trying to allow only users whose Google email is in the `Mail` column in the `MyTable` table. If user is not in the table, redirect to `unauthorized.html`. Right now, if I do not check against the database, login is working OK.

I think I have two concept problems:

1) don't know if the redirect is in `data-redirecturi="http://MyPage.php"` or in `window.location.replace("http://MyPage.php");`

2) I don't know how to redirect to, say, `unauthorized.html` if user's email is not in database.

The html:

```
<div class="WelcomeContainer">
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark" data-redirecturi="http://MyPage.php"></div>
</div>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'signin.php');
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  xhr.onload = function() {
      window.location.replace("http://MyPage.php");
  };
  xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);      
}
</script>
```

The signin.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
$id_token = $_POST['idtoken'];
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

    $Test=false;
    $result = $link->query("SELECT Mail FROM  MyTable");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['Mail']==$payload['email']) {
            $Test=true;
        }
    }

    if ($Test==true) {
        //code here for success?
    }
    else {
        //code here for failure?
    }  
} else {
    die();
}
?>
```

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the XHR part so I have deleted my answer. You will need to return an error `unauthorized` and have your code running in the client process the error.

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8866912/8016720

Comment: Thanks! Your guidelines help me to solve this (although I don't know if the solution is elegant). I'm posting the code in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Following code seems to work.

In the html I replace this:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    window.location.replace("http://MyPage.php");
};
```

with this:

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200) {
        window.location.replace(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```

And in signin.php

```
if ($Test==true) {
  echo "http://www.example.com/TheGoodPage.html";
}
else {
  echo "http://www.example.com/TheUnAuthorizedPage.html";
}
```

Comment: The only immediate issue that I see is with the return url. `http://TheUnAuthorizedPage.html` won't work. Use the full URL. Also if you plan to support HTTPS, then handle that now in your code.

Comment: Edited. Thanks again!